# ODK Collect Error "Select q**stion has no choices"

Tags: odk

I am new to the ODK system. I have been building forms for my organization using ODK formbuilder as I don't know XML or XLSForm. I hope to learn these.

I have already created several simple forms that work fine in collect, but when I have tested the larger, longer version I created I get the error "Select question has no choices". The form I am working on has a wide variety of answer types including location data.

I looked around a bit on the web and didn't come across this problem anywhere. I am unsure why this error occurs - any thoughts?

Comment: Please, add some code. You can doing it by glick n the edit link underneath your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have a "Choose One" or "Select Multiple" question without having added any choices.

P.S. I highly recommend using XLSForms instead. See documentation here: http://xlsform.org/. You can upload your XLSForm to convert it here: http://opendatakit.org/xiframe.